# jQuery star rating slider filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to make a star rating slider filer in jquery but nothing happends.

Filter is:

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse filters-container" id="rating-filter">
    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="five-stars-container editable-rating" data-label-fullrating="5 STELE" data-label-norating="Fara" data-label-rating="STELE" data-rating="1" id="rating"></div><span>TOATE</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Divs to be filtered is :

```
<div data-stars="2">2 STARS</div>
<div data-stars="2">2 STARS</div>
<div data-stars="4">5 STARS</div>
<div data-stars="3">3 STARS</div>
<div data-stars="1">1 STARS</div>
```

And my non working jQuery code is:

```
tjq("#rating").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 4,
    min: 0,
    step: 1,
    max: 5,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var label_rating = '';
        if (ui.value == 0) {
            label_rating = tjq("#rating").data('label-norating');
        } else if (ui.value == 5) {
            label_rating = tjq("#rating").data('label-fullrating');
        } else {
            label_rating = ui.value + ' ' + tjq("#rating").data('label-rating');
        }
        tjq("#rating-filter .panel-content > span").text(label_rating);
        $('div[data-stars]').each(function() {
            var dStars = $(this).attr('data-stars');
            if (dStars < ui.values[0] || dStars > ui.values[1]) $(this).hide();
            else $(this).show();
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance if you could help me sort this out.

Comment: @Mate i dont understand. What ref ?

Comment: yes it is added, i have another price slidee filter wich is working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a0okpqp8/3/

Comment: Now it slides but still not filtering ..

Comment: If the slider is at 3 stars, show only divs with data-stars=3,  hide all otherand so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (dStars < ui.values[0] || dStars > ui.values[1])
```

by

```
if (dStars != ui.value)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a0okpqp8/5/)

```
$("#rating").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 4,
    min: 0,
    step: 1,
    max: 5,

    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var label_rating = '';
        if (ui.value == 0) {
            label_rating = $("#rating").data('label-norating');
        } else if (ui.value == 5) {
            label_rating = $("#rating").data('label-fullrating');
        } else {
            label_rating = ui.value + ' ' + $("#rating").data('label-rating');
        }
        $("#rating-filter .panel-content > span").text(label_rating);
        $('div[data-stars]').each(function() {
            var dStars = $(this).attr('data-stars');

            if (dStars != ui.value) 
               $(this).hide();
            else 
               $(this).show();
        });
    }
});
```